# Talend - Component Creations - Add a line in output

Tags: components, talend

I'm creating a new component Talend. This component have many data in input (example : a Title, a Content, an Extract and an Author) and it returns same data (but Title, Extract and Content have been modified). So, in output I have the Title modified, the Content modified, the Extract modified and the Author (which it has not been modified).

I would that my component returns another line. A line more. An id for example. Is it possible that my component create new "line" and returns them ?

I don't know if I'm understandable... 
Can you help me please ?

Bye.

PS : If you're french : [it's a french forum with my problem](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1223838/logiciels/solutions-dentreprise/business-intelligence/etl/talend/talend-creation-composant-ajout-ligne-sortie/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I must add this in the xml files :

```xml
<PARAMETER NAME="SCHEMA" FIELD="SCHEMA_TYPE" REQUIRED="true" NUM_ROW="10">
   <TABLE READONLY="false">
       <COLUMN NAME="id" TYPE="id_String" LENGTH="255" READONLY="true" CUSTOM="true" />
   </TABLE>
</PARAMETER>
```